# python3: Text file to email body

Tags: python, email, text

i have an output.txt which i want to send its content as an email body.

1.i want to remove specific lines from the content ( not delete from the file itself)

2.i want to be able to convert it to html and to desing some of specific lines size and maybe even color.

i have a working script which sends the mail.
there are some problems:

im not able to remove specific line when using file.read().
when trying readlines() the type is list and the email body is getting messed up.(join doesnt work on list with bytes type)

```
import smtplib
import email.message


def send_email(subject, msg):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        ID = 'XXXX'
        PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXX'
        email_reciever = 'XXXXXX'
        server.login(ID, PASSWORD)
        message = 'Subject:{} \n\n {}'.format(subject, msg)
        server.sendmail(ID, email_reciever, message)

        print('Succes')
    except Exception as e:
        # Print any error messages to stdout
        print(e)
    finally:
        server.quit()


filename = r".\Reports\Report.txt"
with open(filename, "rb") as filename:
    text = filename.read()
msg = email.message.Message()
msg.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
msg.set_payload(text)

subject = "Report"

send_email(subject, msg)
```

Comment: change this line `with open(filename, "rb") as filename:` to `with open(filename, "r") as filename:`

Comment: Great guys you helped me alot! edited to : ```with open(filename, "r") as filename:
    text = ''.join(filename.readlines()[3:])

msg = email.message.Message()
msg.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
msg.set_payload(text.encode())```     what is the easietst way to deliver it as an html format and design it in email body? ( by matching line content )

Comment: The simplest technically is to wrap the text between `<pre>` and `</pre>` and call it a day but this obviouly brings no actual benefits over sending as text/plain. We have no idea what HTML decorations you want so this is really just too broad.

Comment: Just a format to design to content... Choose specific lines to bold or color. What's the simplest method/package?